# Typo3 default configuration overwrites LocalConfiguration.php

Tags: typo3

In TYPO3 6.1.5 the install tool saves configuration values correctly into `LocalConfiguration.php`, but having a look at the Configuration Module in the BE, those values are ignored by TYPO3. When I open the install tool again, all values are replaced by default values.

Any ideas?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Could it be you have some values in ''AdditionalConfiguration.php''? Those constantly override the values of ''LocalConfiguration.php''.

If not - You should definately Check the umask settings in LocalConfiguration.php. There Could be file permission errors involved. This would expand to files generated in typo3temp.

Another option are opcaches like apc. Those may not reload the changed file. Restarting your webserver or fastcgi would be the solution then.